# Misalignment of vertical lines in big LaTEX table

Tags: tables, tabu

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\small
\begin{tabu}{|[2pt] >{\raggedright}m{5cm} |[2pt] >{\centering}m{0.7cm} | >{\centering} m{0.4cm} | >{\centering} m{0.9cm} | >{\centering} m{2cm}| >{\centering}m{1.9cm} | >{\centering}m{1.9cm} |[2pt]}
%\begin{tabu}{|[2pt] >{\centering}p{5cm} |[2pt] >{\centering}p{0.4cm} | >{\centering} p{0.4cm} | >{\centering} p{0.9cm} | >{\centering} p{2cm}| >{\centering}p{1.9cm} | >{\centering}p{1.9cm} |[2pt]}
\tabucline[2pt]{-}  

\multirow{3}{*}{Statements}& \multicolumn{6}{c|[2pt]}{Test Value\,=\,3}\\
\cline{2-7}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{} &\multicolumn{2}{|p{3.8cm}|[2pt]}{95\,\% Confidence Interval of the Difference} \rule{0pt}{4ex}\\[3ex]
\cline{2-7}
& M& TP&    V-valu&  Difference&    Lower&  Upper \\[3ex]
\tabucline[2pt]{-}
IIdentifying wertssdf sdfweds asdwead asdwedasd asdwedasd asdad pattern asdwsdva a s asdasd for comparing the same aweda against the afasd qweqw asdas asdasd..& 9.50&  33& .000&   1.1&    .9& 1.4\\[12ex]

Identifying wertssdf sdfweds asdwead asdwedasd asdwedasd asdad pattern asdwsdva a s asdasd for comparing the same aweda against the afasd qweqw asdas asdasd.&  4.34&   31& .000&   .7& .4& 1.0 \\[12ex]
Identifying wertssdf sdfweds asdwead asdwedasd asdwedasd asdad pattern asdwsdva a s asdasd for comparing the same aweda against the afasd qweqw asdas asdasd., is valuable knowledge.&  6.347&  31& .000&   1.1&    .7& 1.4 \\[10ex]
DIdentifying wertssdf sdfweds asdwead asdwedasd asdwedasd asdad pattern asdwsdva a s asdasd for comparia against the afasd qweqw asdas asdasd. not .&       5.78&   30& .000&   .9& .6& 1.2\\[14ex]
\tabucline[2pt]{-}
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

As you can see there is misalignment at 5 and 6 columns in second row. Why It could be so?

I can not find bug anywhere?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for the first column, vertical rules should always be at the right edge of a column, a rule at the left of a column will not join a rulr at the right of the previous column on the next row, so

```
& \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{2}{p{3.8cm}|[2pt]}{95\,\% Confidence Interval of the Difference} \rule{0pt}{4ex}\\[3ex]
```

not

```
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{} &\multicolumn{2}{|p{3.8cm}|[2pt]}{95\,\% Confidence Interval of the Difference} \rule{0pt}{4ex}\\[3ex]
```